# Recent proliferation of spam on Server Fault

Tags: feature-request, spam

In the past couple of months I'm seeing a *lot* more spam on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour). Until a few months ago I virtually never saw spam, and now virtually every time I visit there are money lenders, abortion pills, call girls, and all kinds of things that most Server Fault visitors probably don't need.

I find now, when I visit, instead of helping people with technical problems, I spend my time marking these questions as spam and then close the site. I don't help people with technical problems as often. I also visit less often, like many people probably do, because there's fewer interesting problems to solve and more spam.

I know there are / were spam prevention measures in place. Have they failed? Have spammers found their way around them? Is anything being done about it?

**Two Suggestions / Feature Requests**

1. Perhaps users with high reputations could completely remove spam questions from the website based on their single vote, or perhaps two votes instead of five votes.
2. Perhaps users with high reputations could report spam more often than once every five seconds. I open the questions in tabs and could report them more quickly than this if the site didn't prevent this.

Here's a screenshot from Server Fault when I visited this afternoon. Eight of the ten questions are spam.

[image: Spam]